Which is the best Qiskit simulator for large quantum circuit?
I have to simulate a quantum circuit with 50 qubits (including 57 Ry gates and at least 60 CNot gates). While transpiling the circuit by Aer-simulator (version: 0.14.2), receiving the following error message 'Number of qubits in circuit is greater than maximum (32) of the coupling_map'.
The question is if there is any other simulators to execute that circuit?

Most probably the Matrix Product State Simulator will do the job.
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

simulator = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state')
job = simulator.run(circ)
print(job.result().get_counts())

For more details, show this post from Qiskit official blog
